# Intellij error with "add non-palette componente"

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

When I try to add a non-palette component in IntelliJ 14.0.3 I get this error:

> Forms added to palette must have a binding for the top-level component

The component that I try to add to a tab of a scrollpane, is a class that extends a JPanel.

I can not understand why this error. With other classes does not give me problems.

The error remains even if I select the two options.

Comment: Formatting, spelling

Comment: Is the component you're trying to add also built with the IntelliJ IDEA UI Designer?

Comment: yes it is built with the IDEA UI Designer. Now I was able to add it through class file. The problem remain if i try to add with through form file.

Answer (score 1):

You may add the form to a pallet and then place it as a component on another form.

To do so open in a designer a form which you want to be custom component. Click right on any group (e.g. swing) and select "Add Component to Palette". After this you can open another form and place the newly added component on it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the "field name" of the JPanel of the form that is being inserted in another form.

It seems this error appears when no field name is specified which means the error is a bit misleading.